# AutoMapper: Defer property mapping to derived maps for abstract base classes

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is it possible in AutoMapper to defer mapping some properties to derived maps? For instance consider the following classes:

```
public abstract class Contract
{
    public int ContractNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RegularContract : Contract { }
public class SpecialContract : Contract { }

public class ContractModel
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a mapping like the following. Observe that the `IsSpecial` property is not mapped in the mapping of `Contract` but in the mappings of the derived classes `RegularContract` and `SpecialContract` instead.

```
public class ContractMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ContractMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Contract, ContractModel>()
        //  .ForMember(t => t.IsSpecial, c => c.Ignore()) // required for valid mapping
            .ForMember(t => t.Nr, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.ContractNumber));

        CreateMap<RegularContract, ContractModel>()
            .IncludeBase<Contract, ContractModel>()
            .ForMember(t => t.IsSpecial, c => c.UseValue(false));

        CreateMap<SpecialContract, ContractModel>()
            .IncludeBase<Contract, ContractModel>()
            .ForMember(t => t.IsSpecial, c => c.UseValue(true));
    }
}
```

Such a configuration is however not valid in AutoMapper because `IsSpecial` is not mapped for `Contract`. In order to make it valid, I would need to add the commented line to the mapping.

However, in such a case AutoMapper will not throw a validation error if the property is not mapped in some derived class, e.g., when I change the mapping of `SpecialContract` to:

```
CreateMap<SpecialContract, ContractModel>()
    .IncludeBase<Contract, ContractModel>(); // no IsSpecial mapping
```

Any ideas how to solve this using AutoMapper mapping inheritance?

Comment: Wouldn't [`AssertConfigurationIsValid()`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) catch a missing property in the derived classes?

Comment: @stuartd: I refined the question. Hopefully, it is more clear now. The point is, that `AssertConfigurationIsValid` will not catch a missing property in the derived class if I put a (required) `Ignore` on it in the base class.